# Update ui components from server event

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

How would I go about updating a UI component when a server process finishes or anytime else for that matter?

Can\Should I

- extend the UI component and register some kind of EventListener on it?
- bind the UI component in a backing bean?
- use some of the new PrimePush features?
- something else?

If anyone could guide me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

**Example Case One**

> Server process ends and updates the database. 
>     I want to automatically 
>   update a DataTable with new rows based on the new information. 
>     I don't want to poll for the new data.

**EDIT**

I want to update the UI component (a primefaces datatable) from an EJB Stateless Bean

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can server push asynchronous changes to a HTML page created by JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787514/how-can-server-push-asynchronous-changes-to-a-html-page-created-by-jsf)

Answer (score 1):

You didnt mention which version of primefaces you are using but you can update components from backed bean with **[addpartialupdatetarget](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.2/)**.

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.addPartialUpdateTarget("myForm:myComponent");
```

Comment: requestContext will be null if it is outside of a client-initiated request  as was the case  here

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the update attribute of your commandButton or whatever else you're using.

Something like this should work

```
<p:dataTable value="#{backer.bean}" id="table">
  // columns with data
</p:dataTable>

<p:commandButton actionListener="#{backer.updateDB}" update="table" />
```

Comment: How do I fire "click"/fire the commandButton from an EJB? Did you read the question correctly? If so could you expand on this solution.