# Refresh p:dataTable without button click

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MainTable
{

    static List<MainTableRow> rows;

    public MainTable()
    {
        rows = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static boolean addRow(MainTableRow mainTableRow)
    {
        return rows.add(mainTableRow);
    }

    public List<MainTableRow> getRows()
    {
        return rows;
    }

    public void setRows(List<MainTableRow> rows)
    {
        MainTable.rows = rows;
    }
}
```

And my xhtml page is:

```
<h:body>
    <h3>Query Modeling Tool - Select Excel file</h3>
    <h:form>
        <p:fileUpload
            fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}"
            mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" update="messages"
            sizeLimit="10000000" fileLimit="3" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xls)$/"
            style="font-size: 14px" />

        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

        <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="mainTableRow"
            value="#{mainTable.rows}" style="font-size: 14px">
            <f:facet name="header">Main Table</f:facet>

            <p:column sortBy="" headerText="Index">
                <h:outputText value="#{mainTableRow.index}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="" headerText="Query">
                <h:outputText value="#{mainTableRow.query}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="" headerText="S1">
                <h:outputText value="#{mainTableRow.s1}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="" headerText="S2">
                <h:outputText value="#{mainTableRow.s2}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="" headerText="S3">
                <h:outputText value="#{mainTableRow.s3}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="" headerText="S9">
                <h:outputText value="#{mainTableRow.s9}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="" headerText="Uygunluk">
                <h:outputText value="#{mainTableRow.uygunluk}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="" headerText="Kural">
                <h:outputText value="#{mainTableRow.kural}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="" headerText="Kaynak">
                <h:outputText value="#{mainTableRow.kaynak}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="" headerText="Query Type">
                <h:outputText value="#{mainTableRow.queryType}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="" headerText="User Intent">
                <h:outputText value="#{mainTableRow.userIntent}" />
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>

    </h:form>

</h:body>
```

"rows" in MainTable is filled by another class, after uploading a file. 
After uploading I want to refresh dataTable without clicking any button.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be solved by one of the following points:

**1.** `<p:fileUpload>` has an attribute `update` that is used to ajax-update the components with a specified list of comma/space-separated ids, so you need to add id of your data table to that attribute:

```
<p:fileUpload ... update="messages dataTable" />
```

**2.** When a file has been uploaded, the table can also be updated programmatically in your action method:

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.addPartialUpdateTarget("<path_to_your_table>");
```

**See also:**

- [jsf/primfaces update ui components from server event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656415/jsf-primfaces-update-ui-components-from-server-event)

Comment: I didn't understand <path_to_your_table>?

Comment: @RongNK Why not simply use `<p:fileUpload ... update="dataTable">`?

Comment: @skuntsel <p:fileUpload ... update="dataTable"> is working thanks. But i already use update for "messages".. How can i write two of them(messages and dataTable) ?

Comment: Just add a comma/space-separated list of ids in PrimeFaces' `update` attribute: `update="messages dataTable"`.

Comment: @skuntsel You should post as answer, i have not worked with JSF for 5 months, so i dont't remember. Sorry OP for the bad answer.

Comment: @RongNK I don't feel like doing so. I think OP should accept your answer with the first clumsy line edited. I'll edit that line if you aren't against it. And also my +1 to keep you up on the track again!