# How to monitor asynchronous/background thread status and get notifications in a JSF component

Tags: jsf, asynchronous, notifications, refresh, monitor

I created few threads in a web application and I have a datatable component in JSF page.

I would like to update the table automatically to show the current status of thread. Is there any prebuild component I can use in this scenario?

Comment: put your code inside {code sample}

Answer (score 6):

> *I created few threads in a web application*

I wholeheartedly hope that you [did it the right way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149919/is-it-safe-to-start-a-new-thread-in-a-jsf-managed-bean) and thus it don't end up in an epic disaster.

---

> *I would like to update the table automatically to show the current status of thread. Is there any prebuild component I can use in this scenario?*

You're basically looking for a technique called "polling" or "pushing". The basic concept of polling is to use JavaScript's `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` to fire a (ajax) HTTP request to the server at intervals and let it process the results accordingly.  The basic concept of pushing is to open a persistent HTTP connection and have the server send small messages over it, this can be done with among others [`WebSocket` in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) and [JSR356 API in Java EE 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/websocket.htm).

At the time of writing, the standard JSF implementation doesn't offer any ready-to-use poll or push component out the box. For the upcoming JSF 2.3, a new `<f:websocket>` tag is currently in progress (see also [issue 1396](https://github.com/jakartaee/faces/issues/1396)).

Your best bet would be a hidden form with a hidden command link/button with `<f:ajax>` and then invoke it by `setInterval()`. Component libraries like [PrimeFaces](https://primefaces.org) however offer ready-to-use components out the box, see also [`<p:poll>` showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml) for some concrete examples. JSF utility library [OmniFaces](https://omnifaces.org) has in its [`<o:commandScript>` showcase](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/commandScript) a poll example and in [`<o:socket>` showcase](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/push/socket) several push examples (the upcoming standard JSF `<f:websocket>` will be largely based on `<o:socket>`).

#### See also:

- [How do I ajax-update a component at an interval of 1 second?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959828/how-do-i-ajax-update-a-component-at-an-interval-of-1-second/)
- [Real time updates from database using JSF/Java EE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947790/real-time-updates-from-database-using-jsf-java-ee)
- [How can server push asynchronous changes to a HTML page created by JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787514/how-can-server-push-asynchronous-changes-to-a-html-page-created-by-jsf/)