# WebSocket OnMessage and ServerEndpoint

Tags: servlets, websocket

I have been reading up on the WebSocket api and have been playing around with it a little bit but I can not get my head wrapped around a few things. Right now I have a servlet `TestServlet` which is defined in `web.xml` to trigger the `doGet` method every time the URL localhost:TestServlet is put into the URL of a browser.

I want to wait for a connection from a mobile device, the guy building the phone app says they can load my servlet, in which case the `doGet` method would trigger and I would do my business with the data received. Only issue is that in the `doGet` method I have the request and the response, can I get the data sting sent from the phone from the request?

I also have my `@ServerEndpoint` set to `/*` which I think means the servlet will be active when a url containing `/TestServlet` is loaded. Problem here is I do not see any output from print lines or see any breakpoints hit.

I am just wondering (if this makes any sense) having the `@ServerEndpoint` set as @ServerEndpoint(value = "/*") will the method annotated `@OnMessage` trigger if a message is there to receive?

If not how can I make it trigger, and if I can not how can I get a data string from an HttpServletRequest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing basic concepts. The `@ServerEndpoint(value)` does not represent an URL pattern like `@WebServlet(urlPatterns)`. It represents the [URI or URI template](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpoint.html#value()). The value of `/*` is just plain wrong. You should not think of it as a servlet (filter). It is not "automagically" invoked on certain `http://` requests either. The client has to explicitly fire a `ws://` request by a.o. `new WebSocket(uri)` in JavaScript (assuming a web application).

E.g.

```
@ServerEndpoint("/push")
public class Push {}
```

with

```
if (window.WebSocket) {
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://example.com/contextname/push");
    ws.onmessage = function(event) {
        var text = event.data;
        console.log(text);
    };
}
else {
    // Bad luck. Browser doesn't support it. Consider falling back to long polling.
    // See http://caniuse.com/websockets for an overview of supported browsers.
    // There exist jQuery WebSocket plugins with transparent fallback.
}
```

#### See also:

- [Real time updates from database using JSF/Java EE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947790/real-time-updates-from-database-using-jsf-java-ee/) (for another concrete example involving websockets with JavaScript)

---

**Update**: it turns out to be a true mobile app (Android/iOS). If the (native) URL/HTTP connection library being used to connect the Servlet by `http://` does not support the `ws://` protocol, then you'd best look for a 3rd party library supporting that. To find one, use keywords ["android websocket client"](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%20websocket%20client), or ["ios websocket client"](https://www.google.com/search?q=ios%20websocket%20client). Note: in documentation/tutorials/blogs, pay attention to the "client" part, not the "server" part, because the "server" part is already implemented by `@ServerEndpoint`.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment as I had updated it to: Now if I understand you correctly, the javascript would run on a page and initialize Socket with an event. For testing I could make a dummy page with just that code on it and test my listener. Putting this code on the main page of my website would start the socket when a user navigates to the site, though I fail to see how a phone could send updates to the server over this socket.

Comment: Needless to say I think you have answered my question in full. Get the WS jar files for android, install them and set up the connection on the phone. This is perfect and I thank you greatly!

Comment: This is great, it looks like I can use the jars to create a stand alone client and use it to connect to the server. As well we can put this on the phone! Now this is slightly unrelated but I think you could help. Where can I upload my server or register my site with the DNS, I do not want to have to connect using ip:port/ProjectName/index.xhtml, any suggestions?

Comment: @BalusC: `@ServerEndpoint("/user")` caters to requests that are going to the url `.../user`. Let's say we have two requests that go to `/user` with the only difference being the message being sent. One message says `create` and another says `delete`. How do you indicate to the rest of the class if it should `create` or `delete` if all you have is one url to define everything?