# Update dataTable from another/external class in PrimeFaces

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fA0NG.png) problem:

[image: shows process]

I have a `<p:dataTable>` in dashboard.xhtml and the appropriate DashboardController.java that loads the data for dataTable.

I also use a HttpServlet for incoming messages. Now, whenever a new message arrives, the Servlet saves the message to the database.

**I want the dataTable to be updated, when the new message arrives.**

I do not want to use the poll-feature and try to get updates every x seconds. Is there a handsome solution?

**By the way:** *I tried to implement the MessageHandler.java functionality into the DashboardController.java (easiest way), but the MessageHandler has to extend from HttpServlet and PrimeFaces seems to struggle with that.*

Comment: Is this acceptable as dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947790/real-time-updates-from-database-using-jsf-java-ee/

Comment: That looks pretty good. I will try it ... Thank you