# JSF schedule an action

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, tomcat, jsf-2

I'm making an auction site (like ebay) with JSF for a project. the server is Apache Tomcat and the db is MySQL.
I need to close an auction when it ends (the time runs out) and notify the seller and the winner.
One way is to schedule a function to run at constant intervals, check for auctions that ended and close them; but is there a way to schedule a function for each auction that will run when the auction ends and will close the auction?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the answer of this question is the way to go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947790/real-time-updates-from-database-using-jsf-java-ee

Comment: @Rami.Q: That answer is mainly about the push part and it being triggered by a database/jpa action. There is nothing in there about the main question in here: _"is there a way to schedule a function for each auction that will run when the auction ends and will close the auction"_: That requires (I guess, not tested) the EJB TimerService, CDI Async with timers or good old Quartz...