# JSP/Servlet dynamic data from model to UI

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I'm trying some little things on JSP and Servlets for a further project.
But I'm now blocked by an idea, but I didn't found a perfect solution to make it works.

The idea is that in a JSP page I've a POST form for my Servlet, to search in some documents. So that the Servlet will create a thread to search in the requested document. But what happens if I want to see the evolution of the search (number of folders explored / total folders for example) meanwhile I continue the navigation on the app, so not on the same page ? 
I imagined a tooltip permanent on the UI, but i didn't found an exact solution to make it possible.

The solution I saw in some post is to use Ajax for asynchronous requests, but I would do the following :

- on the thread (model part) : search, and sometime perform a POST on the JSP page with the evolution of search as content of the POST
- on each JSP page : have something like a "wait for receive" in jQuery, and update the text each time I receive something.

like : 
Form search POST => Servlet : creates a thread, return on the page (no redirect ? )
Thread => POST on JSP page caught by a JS function => update text

But on some posts I always saw the revert function : jQuery/ajax post on something, and use data after...

Can someone give me the right way to do this ?

Many thanks !

Comment: Here's a new search keyword: Push.

Comment: Many thanks, it's really what i want ! I was wondered that nothing was present about this on my newbie tutorial ! Thanks for the quick answer !!

But just one last question, can i use it for multiple page ? For example i'll give a writer from the context to the thread, and he'll send events, but is the event present on the associated page or to all active pages, if I subscribe to the event on each page ?

Comment: In case you're using websocket based push, it's by default sent to all pages. Here's a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25947790 (albeit JSF targeted, pretty much all of code in the top answer is applicable on plain JSP/Servlet too, you only have to replace JSF `<h:form>` snippet by plain HTML/JS code for JSP but that should speak for itself).

Comment: Thanks, perfect for my problem :) !