# Notify the user about the end of the session in JSF 2.3

Tags: jsf, websocket, jsf-2.3

JavaEE, JSF-2.3, Websocket, WebApplication, WildFly.
For each user, a session is created, within which it operates, authorization, authentication, and so on. After 15 minutes of inactivity, the session is automatically destroyed, thanks to the settings of **web.xml** -

```xml
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

In JSF-2.3 available WebSocket, so I decided to do so **ExitBean.java** -

```java
@Inject
@Push(channel = "exit")
PushContext push;

@PreDestroy
public void sessionTimeOut() {
    push.send("exitEvent");
}
```

On the page, respectively, **exit.xhtml** -

```xhtml
<h:form >
  <f:websocket channel="exit" scope="session">
    <f:ajax event="exitEvent" onevent="PF('dlg1').show()"/>
  </f:websocket>
</h:form>
```

At the end of the session, judging by the logs, the `sessionTimeOut()` method works, it's still `@PreDestroy`, but there is no response on the page.
For the test, I placed a button on the **exit.xhtml** page, by clicking on which the `sessionTimeOut()` method is called. When this button is clicked, event - "exitEvent", executes as expected, invoking the PrimeFaces script `PF('dlg1').show()`, which displays a dialog box.
I suspect that websockets are killed even earlier than the `@Predestroy` method is called.
There is another option with the websocket, it looks like this:

```xhtml
<h:form >
  <f:websocket channel="exit" scope="session" onclose="PF('dlg1').show()"/>
</h:form>
```

But it works only when the page loads and again no reaction to the end of the session.
Two questions:

1. How to handle the end of a session using websockets?
2. In extreme cases, offer an alternative.

Comment: I believe to listen to the server timing out sessions you need an HttpSessionListener like this: http://www.groupkt.com/post/7ee95bbd/session-timeout-handling-in-java.htm

Comment: @Melloware: in a `HttpSessionListener` there's no `HttpServletRequest`/`HttpServletResponse` available, so there would be no way to notify the client in some way.

Comment: @BalusC good point. I didn't know you could do this in JSF 2.3 as I am still sadly on JSF 2.1. :) . Your solution below is excellent.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your technical problem is that you didn't specify a function **reference** in `onevent` or `onclose` attribute. It goes like:

```
onevent="function() { PF('dlg1').show() }"
onclose="function() { PF('dlg1').show() }"
```

or

```
onevent="functionName"
onclose="functionName"
```

where `functionName` is defined as a real function:

```
function functionName() {
    PF('dlg1').show();
}
```

---

The correct approach is explained in [Events section of `javax.faces.Push` javadoc](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/faces/push/Push.html#events-client):

```
<f:websocket channel="exit" scope="session" 
    onclose="function(code) { if (code == 1000) { PF('dlg1').show() }}" />
```

or

```
<f:websocket channel="exit" scope="session"  onclose="exitListener" />
```

```
function exitListener(code) {
    if (code == 1000) {
        PF('dlg1').show();
    }
}
```

#### See also:

- [Automatically perform action in client side when the session expires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097565/automatically-perform-action-in-client-side-when-the-session-expires/)
- [Execute JavaScript before and after the f:ajax listener is invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912335/execute-javascript-before-and-after-the-fajax-listener-is-invoked/)