# PrimeFaces poll tag issue with session timeout

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Our application is built on Spring Boot and front end is built using PrimeFaces 6.2 ... Recently we got a requirement to check if the session is active.. i.e say for every 40 minutes from client side we need to make a backing bean call.. and that will call another API to check if the session exists.

From the existing implementation we were using idleMonitor for identifying the idle time from client side and invalidating the session if it reaches 30 minutes.. then user will be redirected to login page

```html
<p:idleMonitor timeout="#{appSesionBean.maxIdleTimeOut}"  
               onidle="PF('timeOut').show();AppUI.showCountDownTimer();"/>
<p:poll interval="#{appSesionBean.getSessionRefreshInterval()}" 
        listener="#{appSesionBean.refreshSession()}"/>
```

As per new requirements, I have added the poll tag configured for 40 minutes to check if the session is active.

The problem that I am facing now is, with the poll tag session is never getting invalidated.. I am refreshing the page after 40-45 minutes and session is still active and user not being redirected to login page.

Since I am new to this PrimeFaces poll and idleMonitor I am wondering if these two can not be placed in the same form?

- Can you please help me if there is an issue with using idleMonitor
  and poll tag?
- Is there any other way I can achieve periodically
  calling a backing bean from client side?
- Can poll tag prevents session invalidation?

Comment: Everytime you do an AJAX request and call a backing bean, your timeout will be resetted. Thats by design.

Comment: Thanks @tandraschko if poll is not reliable in this case, how can this be achieved..? for every 40 minutes I need to call the backing bean provided session is not invalidated?

Comment: short: you cant; each JSF request will touch the session. You can however call a servlet or WS via plain JS.

Comment: thank you @tandraschko I will work on to achieve it with plain JS

Comment: WS is also supported in JSF. Use f:websocket: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51733539.

Answer (score 2):

As @tandraschko pointed out every AJAX call touch the session from JSF thus refreshing your session.

However if you want to track it PrimeFaces Extensions has this clever session component added in 12.0.4+ versions: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/session/basic.jsf

It counts down on the client side based on your users current session timeout and knows how to reset if AJAX calls are made.

Comment: Does the pe:session work across all browser tabs? E.g. when you open 2 browser tabs and the first one is idling longer than session timeout but you're still busy in second tab.

Comment: @BalusC I don't think its multi-tab aware but let me ask the original Dev.

Comment: Confirmed "Nope. The timers over different tabs don't synchronize."

Comment: @BalusC I just added support to Session to make it multiWindowAware! Thanks for the suggestion