# Integration socket.io with Jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces, push-notification, socket.io, integration

Can I integrate Socket.io.js (I already created a server.js,client.html; also work fine in itself.) with existing JSF Project ? (Non-maven and using hibernate,primefaces on Glassfish) How ?

Or another way to solve Send server push notifications to cliets ?

Comment: Uhhhmmmmm... _"Or another way to solve Send server push notifications to cliets ?"_ PrimeFaces push?

Comment: is it better than node.js or socket.io ?

Comment: It is fully integrated with jsf/primefaces... big advantage

Comment: Any idea about socket.io & jsf integratino ?

Comment: No I have not, sorry.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3787514