# How to implement async calls from session bean

Tags: jsf, asynchronous

In the oficial Java EE documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html says "Session beans can implement asynchronous methods".
Following this tutorial I'm not able to execute a method asynchronously.

It actually Works, but like any other synchronous method. (It doesn´t start any other thread).

```
@ManagedBean(name = "inicioSSCCBean") 
@SessionScoped
public class InicioSSCCBean implements Serializable {

    ...

    @Asynchronous
    public Future<String> sendMessage() {
        String status;
        try {
            // Call to SAP server...
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            // Error handler
        }
        return new AsyncResult<String>(status);
    }

    public void otherMethod() {
        String result = sendMessage().get();    // The result is what I expect
        System.out.println(result); 
    }

    ...

}
```

Do anyone know how to implement an async call from a session bean? 
The main goal is to make a call to a SAP service, and get the results asynchronously.

I´m using JSF 2.2, PrimeFaces.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean it works but like any other synchronous method? Show us how you used it.

Comment: Let me know if I could make it more clear and sorry about my bad english.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You misunderstood the Java EE tutorial. The term "Session bean" refers to enterprise session beans (EJBs), not to session scoped managed beans (JSF/CDI beans).

The [`@javax.ejb.Asynchronous`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Asynchronous.html) annotation, as its package already hints, works only in EJBs. EJBs are recognizable by having a `@javax.ejb.Xxx` annotation on the class, such as `@Stateless` or `@Stateful`.

Below is the correct kickoff example:

```
@Stateless
public class YourService {

    @Asynchronous
    public void asyncDoSomething() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

```
@ManagedBean
public class YourBean {

    @EJB
    private YourService yourService;

    public void submit() {
        yourService.asyncDoSomething();
    }

}
```

#### See also:

- [When is it necessary or convenient to use Spring or EJB3 or all of them together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369356/when-is-it-necessary-or-convenient-to-use-spring-or-ejb3-or-all-of-them-together)
- [Is it safe to start a new thread in a JSF managed bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149919/is-it-safe-to-start-a-new-thread-in-a-jsf-managed-bean)
- [JSF Controller, Service and DAO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639785/jsf-controller-service-and-dao)
- [How can server push asynchronous changes to a HTML page created by JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787514/how-can-server-push-asynchronous-changes-to-a-html-page-created-by-jsf)

Comment: It's very important analyze the safety of threads when you are working with JSF. Ther's a enormeous probability of user start many threads for the same task... Thanks for the suggestions @BC.

Comment: @Cold: See also 2nd "See also" link. That part is already elaborated over there along with concrete examples.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that you're trying to use the wrong kind of bean, you'll have to understand how `Future` works.

When you call `Future.get()`, the thread will block until the `Future` has a result. Therefore `sendMessage().get()` will act exactly like a synchronous call.

However if you call `sendMessage()` and then perform other tasks before calling `get()`, it will be performed asynchronously. As you realize an asynchronous call is only useful when you don't need the result right away, making it less useful than it seems in most cases.

Comment: I tried whithout the get() method but it keeps working the same way. I´m using a JBoss AS 7 server. Don´t know if any specific configuration is needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ah, the second common problem. You can't call the asynchronous method it from the same class. You'd want a service class (for example) with the asynchronous method injected into your bean.

Comment: No, `@Asynchronous` has no effect at all in JSF managed beans.

Comment: @BalusC Oh, I missed that completely (and it's been quite a while since I've been involved with pure Java EE). However he did fall into the trap of calling `get()` immediately.