# WildFly 12.0.0.Final JSF 2.3 & f:websocket - Class loader issue

Tags: wildfly, cdi, weld, jboss-weld, jsf-2.3

Trying to get an EJB to notify my XHTML JSF page when a document (row) has been inserted into a MongoDB collection.

Got JSF 2.3 working thanks to the answer to my earlier question:

[f:websocket in JSF 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49854566/fwebsocket-in-jsf-2-3)

However after adding the serverside code to my EJB and trying to deploy my EAR to WildFly 12.0.0.Final I get a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for PushContext:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.notifywell.ejb.FoodsCosmeticsMedicinesEJB with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.NOTiFYwell.ear.NOTiFYwellJAR.jar" from Service Module Loader

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.push.PushContext from [Module "deployment.NOTiFYwell.ear.NOTiFYwellJAR.jar" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:199)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    ... 18 more
```

used in EJB:

```
@Inject
@Push
private PushContext push;
```

contained in:

```
jboss-jsf-api_2.3_spec-2.3.3.SP1.jar
```

This occurs when I add the `@Inject` to the `@Push`.

Any issues with CDI in WildFly 12 and/or JSF 2.3?

Comment: The ejb layer (backend) should not know anything about push (frontend). Use cdi events in the ejb) with observers in the frontend to communicate the two layers. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947790/real-time-updates-from-database-using-jsf-java-ee

Comment: I was following BalusC's JSF 2.3+ example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787514/how-can-server-push-asynchronous-changes-to-a-html-page-created-by-jsf.

Comment: Correct, but If you look closely, you'll see the push being used in the frontend cdi bean (in the war) which also has an observes for events and the event is thrown in the stateless ejb. No 'push' is in the EJB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *used in EJB:*
>
> ```
> @Inject
> @Push
> ```

You should never use frontend-targeted libraries in EJBs. This way your EJBs become tight coupled to the JSF frontend and totally unreusable for other frontends such as JAX-RS, JSP/Servlet, etc.

The `@Push` documentation even [explicitly](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/faces/push/Push.html#usage-server) mentions to inject it in WAR side only.

#### See also:

- [why shouldn't entity bean be managed by JSF framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431338/why-shouldnt-entity-bean-be-managed-by-jsf-framework/)
- [JSF Controller, Service and DAO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639785/jsf-controller-service-and-dao/)

---

> *add the 'jboss-jsf-api_2.3_spec-2.3.3.SP1.jar' to my deployed EAR/JAR:*

You should never add duplicate classes to the runtime classpath. It will only confuse the class loaders. The particular library is already provided by the target runtime (WildFly) itself. You do not need to provide it from the deployment on.

#### See also:

- [How to properly install and configure JSF libraries via Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081234/how-to-properly-install-and-configure-jsf-libraries-via-maven/)

---

> *Any issues with CDI in WildFly 12 and/or JSF 2.3?*

Not for me. [The OmniFaces showcase](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/push/socket) currently runs WildFly 12 with JSF 2.3 and the OmniFaces counterpart of `@Push` works just fine.

You only need to keep in mind to [explicitly](http://wildfly.org/news/2018/02/28/WildFly12-Final-Released/) instruct WildFly 12 to use `standalone-ee8.xml` when you intend to use JSF 2.3 on it. Also when used in the IDE. In Eclipse, when creating the server, you can specify it in the *Configuration file* entry of *New Server* wizard, which defaults to `standalone.xml`.

[image]

If you're still facing class loading trouble, then it can only mean that you have messed up the runtime classpath in other way. This can have more causes which are not visible in the information provided so far. For a starter like you who doesn't immediately mention the classpath configuration in a question about classpath trouble (and thus indicates ignorance about it), it's best to not mess around with the runtime classpath (or the "Build Path" and "Libraries" as called in the average IDE) until you grok it. Java EE provides by default already everything out the box, there's **absolutely no need** to adjust libraries in the project.

Leave everything as default, inject `@Push` in WAR instead of EJB and tell WildFly to run in EE8 mode and everything should go well.

#### See also:

- [What exactly is Java EE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295096/what-exactly-is-java-ee)

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed explanation. The issue was the @ Inject @ Push in the EJB, moved to a POJO. I'd removed the WildFly JSF 2.3 JAR from the EAR & WAR and it deploys fine. I also had an issue with the beanManager.fireEvent. This was caused by using the deprecated: javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped switched to javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped and the observers works.