# JSF 2.3 & o:socket or f:websocket - Nothing 'pushed' to the client

Tags: jsf, wildfly, omnifaces, jsf-2.3

After help from @BalusC I have my EJB method firing an event on JBoss WildFly 12.0.0.Final (MacOS) using JSF 2.3 running on EE8:

```
beanManager.fireEvent("updateNotifications" );
```

the POJO:

```
@Inject
@Push(channel = "testChannel")
private PushContext pushContext;

public void onPersist(@Observes String notification) {
    logger.info("***** onPersist notification = {}", notification);
    pushContext.send("updateNotifications");
}
```

receives & prints the message;

> 16:03:36,682 INFO  [com.notifywell.ejb.FoodsCosmeticsMedicinesEJB]
>   (default task-3) >>>>> insertFoodsCosmeticsMedicinesEJB beanManager =
>   Weld BeanManager for NOTiFYwell.ear/NOTiFYwellJAR.jar/ [bean count=39]
>
> 16:03:36,695 INFO  [com.notifywell.push.PushBean] (default task-3)
>   ***** onPersist notification = updateNotifications

I can’t get it to communicate with XHTML from the Push Send. I’ve tried with both OmniFaces 3.1 & the JBoss WildFly 12 JSF 2.3 and nothing re-renders (XHTML code not shown here). When using OmniFaces 3.1 I can’t get the onmessage to display:

```
<h:form>
    <o:socket channel="testChannel" onmessage="socketListener"/>
    <h:outputScript>
        function socketListener(message, channel, event) {
            console.log(message);
        }
    </h:outputScript>
</h:form>
```

If I open the console log in Chrome it's empty there's no “message”.

In WireShark I see:

> 2601 9.810264 ::1 ::1 HTTP 997 GET
>   /NOTiFYwell/omnifaces.push/testChannel?a1ef3363-dc5a-4153-a4c7-73b0e183713d
>   HTTP/1.1

It is as though the

```
pushContext.send(notification);
```

is not getting executed.

Comment: did you debug network traffic in the browser?

Comment: Using Wireshark and filtering on tcp.port == 8080 && http. I see my unit test running. Does show the HTTP GET and the response of OK 200.

Comment: _"It is as though the `pushContext.send(notification)` is not getting executed."_ Debug...

Comment: uhhhh if you run your app in a container from your ide you should just be able to debug...

Comment: If you have an [mcve] I can try to reproduce. But I'm not going to try to reproduce. But does the f: websockets work? Does that make a difference?

Comment: oh cool... I did not help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49854566/fwebsocket-in-jsf-2-3 and all the other comments were not help either? Hmmmm....

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same Situation with Wildfly 14.

To resolve this i had to:

1. undeploy the Application
2. shutdown the Server
3. clear the content of the tmp folder in standalone
4. start server
5. deploy

Now it works, but if I deploy without steps 1-4 it wont work again. 
(Maybe Step 3 is not necessary, but i do it because i got so many other errors)