# Growl message does not show up when created in method triggered by <p:commandButton async="true">

Tags: jsf, primefaces

im currently creating a litte application with spring boot and primefaces and have the problem, that i cant create a error message in my website if there went something wrong.
Here some code of the xhtml:

```
<h:form id="form">
<p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>
...
<p:commandButton id="btnStartManualCopy" styleClass="pollUpdate" async="true" value="Start" disabled="#{daqScriptController.isProcessing()}" action="#{daqScriptController.startManualCopy}" />
</h:form>
```

note that async is true so the page does not block while the called method 'startManualCopy' is processing.
inside the method 'startManualCopy' i also handle errors if there are any while processing and want to display specified messaged on the page - within the growl.
What i have tried so far:

```
FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error:", "Some cool text); FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
```

or:

```
PrimeFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update(":msgs");
```

or:

```
final RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.update(":msgs");
```

note: i tried for the ids some other combinations like :form:msgs and so on - so i can be sure that the right component is adressed. but in the network observer the response never really had an update inside.

what i found out while debugging was, that the responewriter is null in the facescontext inside the async called method. i added a listener, which adds a message to the growl on a tabclose event and this works just fine.

```
public void onTabClose(TabCloseEvent event) {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Tab Closed", "Closed tab: " + event.getTab().getTitle());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}
```

so any idea how i can display the error messages from my usecase?

thanks

Comment: Start reading here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787514/how-can-server-push-asynchronous-changes-to-a-html-page-created-by-jsf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `update="msgs"` in your commandButton to tell it to update the msgs component after the AJAX return.

```xml
<p:commandButton async="true" 
    value="Start"  
    action="#{daqScriptController.startManualCopy}" 
    update="msgs" />
```

Comment: Wouldn't all this in the question fail too when not using async? Since a missing update does not update anything? (I mislead by the async part)

Comment: ya thanks.. that did the job. but i was pretty sure i had this in my first attempt but seems like i had a litte other misstake there.

Comment: @white91wolf so most likely it is not async related. Next time pay good attention when creating questions