# Using poll to show progress on long running tasks

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a long running task in my bean, so I would like to show some progress. I'm using `progressBar` just fine, but I would like to show some extra information besides a progress bar. Basically I would like to show a list of strings in a `dataTable` or similar, showing progress messages as they're generated.

But I haven't found a way of progressively display new rows in a dataTable, while a bean method is executing. By the nature of Primefaces/JSFs, any string I add to the `dataTable`'s binded bean variable is only shown when the whole method finishes. Primefaces' `progressBar` works fine because it polls the backing bean with AJAX calls, so it's able to draw progress while a bean method is running, but other components don't work this way.

I've tried splitting my big bean method `longTask()` (which is basically a for loop) in individual calls `executeNextTask()` (that performs a single iteration), and using Primefaces `poll` component to call them:

```xhtml
<p:poll widgetVar="myPoll" interval="1" autoStart="false" listener="#{myBean.executeNextTask()}" update="myDataTable"/>
<p:commandButton value="Start process" onclick="PF('myPoll').start();"/>

<p:dataTable value="#{myBean.messageList}">
...
</p:dataTable>
```

```java
List<String> messageList;

void executeNextTask() {
  if (!this.myObjects.isEmpty()) {
    Object o=this.myObjects.remove(0);
    // Perform task
    messageList.add("Processed object: "+o.toString());
  } else {
    Primefaces.current().executeScript("PF('myPoll').stop()");
  }
}
```

It more or less works, but if any call to `executeNextTask()` takes more time than specified in `poll`'s interval, subsequent calls may overlap, which is undesirable.

Is there any way to perform what I want, either with `poll` or by using other components/techniques?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787514/how-can-server-push-asynchronous-changes-to-a-html-page-created-by-jsf

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a way around it without having to use websockets (which I find a little bit overkill for such a simple UI task). Since `p:poll` does everything that I want except avoiding overlapping, I've implemented overlapping detection in the bean itself:

```java
List<String> messageList;
boolean taskInProgress;

void initBatch() {
  this.taskInProgress=false;
  this.messageList=new ArrayList<String>();
}

void executeNextTask() {
  if (!taskInProgress) {
    this.taskInProgress=true;
    if (!this.myObjects.isEmpty()) {
      Object o=this.myObjects.remove(0);
      // Perform task
      messageList.add("Processed object: "+o.toString());
    } else {
      Primefaces.current().executeScript("PF('myPoll').stop()");
    }
    this.taskInProgress=false;
  }
}
```

Client side:

```html
<p:commandButton value="Start process" 
  onclick="PF('myPoll').start();" actionListener="#{myBean.initBatch()}" />
<p:poll widgetVar="myPoll" interval="1" autoStart="false" 
  listener="#{myBean.executeNextTask()}" stop="#{myBean.myObjects.isEmpty()}" 
  update="myDataTable"/>

<p:dataTable value="#{myBean.messageList}">
...
</p:dataTable>
```

This way bean method executions may overlap, but overlaps are detected and managed. It's not the cleanest solution, but it works. Too bad `p:poll` doesn't provide a `dontOverlap='true'` or similar, it would make the component much more useful and easier to use.